# Use Antd select with mode tags but allow only one selection

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Antd Select for a project. My requirement is to use Select with **mode='tags'** as it allows  user to create a new option, but I also want user to select only one option at a time (i.e either have a new option created or have an existing option selected shown in the select box). I tried using **autoClearSearchValue** but is of no use.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `<Select />` to be controlled component.
I write an example, the key logic is to control the selected value in `onChange` function;

```js
export default function MyTest() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                mode="tags"
                onChange={(value, options) => {
                    // update data only when select one item or clear action
                    if (options?.length === 0 || options?.length === 1) {
                        setData(value);
                    }
                }}
                value={data}
                options={[
                    {
                        label: "0",
                        value: "0",
                    },
                    {
                        label: "1",
                        value: "1",
                    },
                    {
                        label: "2",
                        value: "2",
                    },
                ]}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hey @RedYin. Thanks for the answer. Pretty much solved the issue. Just one thing though. Since the initial value is **null**, theres a blank tag on the screen now and hence the placeholder is not visible.

Comment: Oh, there is a mistake in my code, it's better to use `string[]` type for data and the initial value should be empty array. So there will be no blank tag on the screen.